# common lisp auto completion on aquamacs

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, lisp, common-lisp, aquamacs

When I start aquamacs with the autocompletion program
installed, http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/, with a lisp file that has `el` as an extension (`example.el`)
Then all lisp features are loaded into `aquamacs` including autocompletion.
But when I load a common lisp file (`example.lisp`) no autocompletion features are loaded.

So my question is, is it possible
to change the autocompletion code so also common lisp files are
recognized?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From autocomplete manual:

> #### Enable `auto-complete-mode` automatically for specific modes
>
> `auto-complete-mode` won't be enabled automatically for modes that are
>   not in `ac-modes`. So you need to set if necessary:

```
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'brandnew-mode)
```

Or in your case

```
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'lisp-mode)
```

Just for info. By default the following modes are included

```
(defcustom ac-modes
  '(emacs-lisp-mode
    lisp-interaction-mode
    c-mode cc-mode c++-mode
    java-mode clojure-mode scala-mode
    scheme-mode
    ocaml-mode tuareg-mode
    perl-mode cperl-mode python-mode ruby-mode
    ecmascript-mode javascript-mode js-mode js2-mode php-mode css-mode
    makefile-mode sh-mode fortran-mode f90-mode ada-mode
    xml-mode sgml-mode)
  "Major modes `auto-complete-mode' can run on."
  :type '(repeat symbol)
  :group 'auto-complete)
```

Comment: I added (add-to-list 'ac-modes 'lisp-mode) in .emacs and I also added lisp-mode in auto-complete.el but it still doesn't work

Comment: It worked for me. I just installed it and executed (add-to-list 'ac-modes 'lisp-mode). Have you restarted the emacs or executed (add-to-list 'ac-modes 'lisp-mode)   ? Your mode for lisp files is lisp-mode, right?

Comment: did everything, restarted aquamacs, added (add-to-list 'ac-modes 'lisp-mode)  to .emacs etc, but still aquamacs enter the normal lisp mode on *.lisp files. I'm not sure about my mode for lisp files. could be slime, or lisp.mode. could that be the reason it doesn't work?

Comment: Try to do M-x lisp-mode in your lisp file. If it doesn't work try M-x emacs-lisp-mode.

Comment: loading a *.lisp file and do M-x lisp-mode did not solve it, but loading M-x emacs-lisp-mode activates auto-complete, so in a way the problem is solved. thanks